# Sed capital letter doesnt work in regex group

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have text:

> abc abc Abc ABC AB_C

I want to match words with capital letters and dash( this is not obligatory).

My solution is:

```
[A-Z]+(_{0,1}[A-Z]+)+
```

And it works on [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5BA-Z%5D%2b%28_%7B0,1%7D%5BA-Z%5D%2b%29%2b&input=abc%20abc%20Abc%20ABC%20AB_C) but it doesn't work with `sed`. What am I doing wrong?

```
sed 's/\([A-Z]+(_{0,1}[A-Z]+)+\)/\1/g'
```

Comment: @Lutz this will not take AB_C

Comment: So you're searching for uppercase words that have an underscore in them and then replace them with themselves again? The first pair of parentheses in your expression captures such words. I don't understand the question. Do you only want to match such words or do you also want to replace such words?

Comment: @diveshpremdeep I am using pipe, I didn't show whole inctruction.

Comment: I followed your link to regexpal. Right at the top it says "regexpal 0.1.4 — a JavaScript regular expression tester". Sadly, just about every tool that implements regular expressions implements them differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That regex isn't supported in traditional sed. You can use `grep -oP` (with PCRE flag)

```
s='abc abc Abc ABC AB_C'
grep -oP '([A-Z]+(_?[A-Z]+)+)' <<< "$s"
ABC
AB_C
```

Comment: `PCRE` => Perl Compatible Regular Expressions

Comment: The "plain" grep would be `grep -o '\<[A-Z]\+\(_[A-Z]*\)*\>'`. I would use `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]`

Answer (score 1):

by default `sed` uses BRE. which means, you have to escape the chars with special meaning, like `+ ( ...`. to "give" them special meaning.

if you are using gnu sed, you can use `-r` option to make sed use `ERE`.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: @PsychoData The Basic Regular Expressions . ERE=Extended RE

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two ways:

1. With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) filtering lower-case letters:

   ```
   $ echo 'abc abc Abc ABC AB_C' | sed "s/\s/\n/g" | sed '/[a-z]/d' 
   ABC
   AB_C
   ```
2. With [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) using not the [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre):

   ```
   $ echo 'abc abc Abc ABC AB_C' | sed "s/\s/\n/g" | grep "^[A-Z][A-Z_]*$"
   ABC
   AB_C
   ```